# Xcode version to 9, iOS11 and works fine except iPhone x. UI got collapsed

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, ios11, iphone-x, safearealayoutguide

1. I have Created Two `UIView` one `headerview` and second is `UICollectionView` both subview of `UIScrollView` and I have hidden my `NavigationBar` entire app.
2. Now I have added below code for set **"SafeAreaLayoutGuides"** in iOS11 but here application crass due to **superview** **nil** found.

> I have added below code.

```
    UIView *parentView = self.view.superview;
    UIView *childView = scrollViewMain.superview;
    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint;
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint;

    if (@available(iOS 11, *)) {
        topConstraint   = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

        bottomConstraint   = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    } else {
        topConstraint   = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];

        bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    }

    [parentView addConstraint:topConstraint];
    [parentView addConstraint:bottomConstraint];
```

Comment: Where is code??

Comment: sorry... i just updated.@RonakThakkar

Comment: I have some issue in iOS11.

Comment: When are you calling this? awakeFromNib? viewDidLoad? viewWillAppear? What is the exact error message you‘re getting, and where does it show up? Compiler results? Console log?

Comment: On viewWillAppear method.

Comment: can u share ur screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

If `parentView` is nil (because `self.view.superview` is `nil`), then that means that `self.view` hasn't been added to the view hierarchy yet.

Make sure that whatever view contains this one has called `self.addSubview(childView)`; that'll fix the "`nil` superview" issue.